# Problems in custom styling a browse input button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a custom styled browse button. To achieve this I have this html code:

```
<label class="usp-label usp-label-files usp-label-file usp-label-file-single" for="usp-file-single">Image/Logo <span class="required">*</span></label>
<div id="file">Browse</div>
<span class="small-text">max size 5 MB</span>
```

css:

```
.usp-pro-form label {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
}

#file {
    display:none;
    background-color:  #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var wrapper=$('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'}); 
var fileInput =  $(':file').wrap(wrapper); 
fileInput.change(function(){$this = $(this); $('#file').text($this.val());
}); 
$('#file').click(function(){alert('bla');    fileInput.click();
}).show();});
```

So, the browse button should appear with a grey background, while the label should just be black text with white background. Instead it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: What is fileinput.click? This doesn't seem to be a valid upload button.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0q7so8he/) is a fiddle with the css and html you have provided (I got rid of display:none).  The button looks fine.  You must have a problem with some other part of your code/css.

Comment: It comes from line 3 in the javascript code. It's a variable that contains an actual file input